# csh script inherit envirionment variables?

Tags: solaris, csh

I found an odd problem when I run a simple csh script on Solaris.

```
#!/bin/csh
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Let's call this script `test`. When I run this:

```
shell> echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
shell> /usr/lib:/usr/openwin/lib:/usr/dt/lib:/usr/local/lib:/lib:/my_app/lib
shell> ./test
shell> /usr/lib:/usr/openwin/lib:/usr/dt/lib:/usr/local/lib:/lib
```

They print out totally different values for $LD_LIBRARY_PATH. I can't figure out why. (It's OK on my linux machine)

Thanks!

Comment: why are you using csh? use bash or sh and see if you get the desired results. try using a trying name instead of "test", eg "myscript".

Comment: Thanks, bash script runs OK! But why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you set `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in your `$HOME/.cshrc`?

[You really shouldn't](http://xahlee.info/UnixResource_dir/_/ldpath.html) if you do, since it often just breaks software, but changing the first line of the script to `#!/bin/csh -f` will cause your script to not read `.cshrc` files at the start, protecting you from other users who made that mistake.

Comment: Thank you! I should think about that.

Answer (score 0):

If your interactive shell is in the sh/ksh family you might have set LD_LIBRARY_PATH using "set" but not exported it.  In that case it's new value will be set like a normal variable, but not exported into the environment.  But it's more likely that your script is reinitializing the variable.

You can use the "env" command to dump out the exported environment from the interactive shell to check this.